# Is using navigation properties to "Add" related items slow?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have a `Device` with a list of other `DeviceLogEntry`.  `device.Logs` is a navigational property and I currently add new logs like so

```
device.Logs.Add(newEntry);
```

Logs is defined as so

```
public virtual ICollection<DeviceLogEntry> Logs { get; set; }
```

My question is will this load the entire `Logs` table before adding the new one? If so (this would be really slow as Logs contains LOTS of entries).  What would be a better (faster) alternative?

Comment: You can easily check that starting SQL Profiler and checking what SQL is being send to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue they aren't fixing just now: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/683

Couple of things you could try.

1. Disable lazy loading for the entity by removing virtual
2. Do the addition the other way around if applicable

For point 2, would be a case of exposing the DeviceId on your log table, and instead of doing:

```
device.Logs.Add(newEntry);
```

would to do something like:

```
newEntry.DeviceId = _deviceId;
context.Logs.Add(newEntry);
```

Comment: It's possible that 2 doesn't solve the problem because adding the log to the context will internally add the log to the device's log collection as well (relationship fixup) and thereby trigger lazy loading. Now, it's mentioned at the bottom of the thread you linked that the problem has been fixed at Jan, 10th 2014. I'm not sure if the fix is already in the most recent EF 6 release or only prepared for EF 7. But for sure it isn't in EF 5 or earlier. Setting `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before loading the device is probably the safest solution right now.